# Returning a complex object from an Oracle package to C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a stored procedure inside an Oracle package from C# and get a complex object returned. It's a simple case of a parent record (devsite) with multiple children (parcels).

In the package definition:

```
TYPE PARCEL_Record IS RECORD (
    PIN varchar2(100),
    ADDRESS varchar2(100)
);

TYPE PARCEL_Table IS TABLE OF PARCEL_Record;

TYPE DEVSITE_Record IS RECORD (
    PRCLID varchar2(100),
    PARCELS PARCEL_Table
);

PROCEDURE Test(DevsiteId IN varchar2, Output OUT DEVSITE_Record);
```

In the package body:

```
PROCEDURE Test(DevsiteId IN varchar2, Output OUT DEVSITE_Record) IS
BEGIN

    Output.PRCLID := DevsiteId;
    
    Output.PARCELS := PARCEL_Table();
    
    Output.PARCELS.extend;
    Output.PARCELS(1).PIN := 'PIN1';
    Output.PARCELS(1).ADDRESS := 'Address 1';

    Output.PARCELS.extend;
    Output.PARCELS(2).PIN := 'PIN2';
    Output.PARCELS(2).ADDRESS := 'Address 2';

    Output.PARCELS.extend;
    Output.PARCELS(3).PIN := 'PIN3';
    Output.PARCELS(3).ADDRESS := 'Address 3';
    
END;
```

I can call this just fine from within SQL Developer and inspect the results.

```
declare
    output MYPKG.DEVSITE_Record;
begin
    MYPKG.Test('111', output);
    dbms_output.put_line(output.Parcels(2).Address); --> gives me 'Address 2'
end;
```

I have the mappings in C# set up as

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("MYPKG.PARCEL_RECORD")]
public class ParcelDataFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
{
    #region IOracleCustomTypeFactory

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new ParcelData();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ParcelData : IOracleCustomType, INullable
{
    [OracleObjectMapping("PIN")]
    public string PIN { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("ADDRESS")]
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull { get; private set; }

    public static ParcelData Null { }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt) { }
    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt) { }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("MYPKG.PARCEL_TABLE")]
public class ParcelTableFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
{ 
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new ParcelTable();
    }

    public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
    {
        return new ParcelData[numElems];
    }

    public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
    {
        return new OracleUdtStatus[numElems];
    }
}

public class ParcelTable : IOracleCustomType, INullable
{
    [OracleArrayMapping()]
    public ParcelData[] Parcels { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull { get; private set; }

    public static ParcelTable Null{ }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt) { }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt) { }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("MYPKG.DEVSITE_RECORD")]
public class DevsiteDataFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
{
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new DevsiteData();
    }
}

public class DevsiteData : IOracleCustomType, INullable
{
    [OracleObjectMapping("PRCLID")]
    public string PRCLID { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("PARCELS")]
    public ParcelTable Parcels { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull { get; private set; }

    public static DevsiteData Null { }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt) { }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt { }
}
```

I've excluded the code for ToCustomObject() and Null() because I set breakpoints on all of them and none get hit so the error is happening before then. This

```
        using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();

                cmd.CommandText = "MYPKG.Test";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("DevsiteId", devsiteId);

                var outParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add(
                    new OracleParameter()
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object,
                        ParameterName = "Output",
                        UdtTypeName = "MYPKG.DEVSITE_Record"
                    });

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                return (DevsiteData)outParameter.Value;
            }
        }
```

Dies on ExecuteNonQueryAsync() with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: MYPKG.PARCEL_TABLE is invalid
   at OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTNamedType.GetNamedTypeMetaData(OracleConnection conn, OracleCommand getTypeCmd)
   at OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTTypeCache.GetMetaData(OracleConnection conn, UDTNamedType udtType)
   at OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTTypeCache.CreateUDTType(OracleConnection conn, String schemaName, String typeName)
   at OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTTypeCache.GetUDTType(OracleConnection conn, String schemaName, String typeName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.GetUDTType(OracleConnection conn, String schemaName, String typeName)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.GetUDTTypeFromCache(String schemaName, String typeName)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.GetUDTType(OracleConnection conn)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_UDT(OracleConnection conn)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnectionImpl connImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bMetadataModified, Int32 arrayBindCount, ColumnDescribeInfo& paramMetaData, Object& paramValue, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, SqlStatementType stmtType)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.InitializeParamInfo(ICollection paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[] cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bMetadataModified, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindValuesHelper)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ProcessParameters(OracleParameterCollection paramColl, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, ColumnDescribeInfo[] cachedParamMetadata, Boolean& bBindMetadataModified, Boolean isEFSelectStatement, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindValuesHelper)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

So it looks like my mapping is not correct, but I can't see where? There are plenty of examples on here for returning/mapping a table of user-defined objects, but I have found none that return a child table as a property of another object.

Comment: The error is `MYPKG.PARCEL_TABLE is invalid` what do you get when you do `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'MYPKG' AND TYPE IN ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY');`? If you have errors then fix those first before trying to use it in C#.

Comment: Alternatively, you might need to use `SCHEMA_NAME.MYPKG.PARCEL_TABLE` rather than `MYPKG.PARCEL_TABLE` as Oracle will think you are using `SCHEMA.OBJECT` rather than `PACKAGE.OBJECT` and there is not a `MYPKG` schema.

Comment: Although even if you fix that I'm not convinced it will work as C# drivers tend to support PL/SQL associative array data-types (`TABLE OF X INDEX BY Y`) and not SQL or PL/SQL non-associative array data-types (`TABLE OF X`). I don't know why as drivers for other languages do support non-associative arrays.

Comment: ALL_ERRORS shows nothing, and I can also execute it successfully directly in Oracle so the package itself is fine.